# Call Delphi dll from go

Tags: delphi, go, dllimport

I have a Delphi dll that needs to be called from golang (go). I can load and call the dll using syscall.Syscall, or windows.Call. Both methods execute the dll correctly. The dll returns its result by changing a string buffer that is passed to it. When I later inspect the string, it is empty (in syscall) or panics in windows.Call. I have tried several permutations but haven't had any luck getting my value out of the variable that should store the result.

Example using windows.Call:

```
    // Package getSID calls SIDgenerator and generates a SID for Retail Pro
    package main

    import (
        "fmt"
        "unsafe"

        "golang.org/x/sys/windows"

        "unicode/utf16"
    )

    var (
        sidgeneratorDLL, _ = windows.LoadDLL("sidgenerator64.dll")
        getRandomSID, _    = sidgeneratorDLL.FindProc("GetRandomSID")
    )

    // StringToCharPtr converts a Go string into pointer to a null-terminated cstring.
    // This assumes the go string is already ANSI encoded.
    func StringToCharPtr(str string) *uint8 {
        chars := append([]byte(str), 0) // null terminated
        return &chars[0]
    }

    // GetRandomSID generates random SID, UPC SID or ALU SID
    func GetRandomSID(Buffer []uint16, BufSize uint64) (result byte) {
        // var nargs uintptr = 2
        fmt.Println(Buffer)
        ret, _, callErr := getRandomSID.Call(uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(&Buffer)),
            uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(&BufSize)))

        // fmt.Println("Buffer", Buffer)

        if callErr != nil {
            fmt.Println("===== CallErr =====")
            fmt.Println(ret, callErr)
            //  fmt.Println("Buffer", Buffer)
        }
        result = byte(ret)
        return
    }

    func main() {
        defer sidgeneratorDLL.Release()
        buffer := utf16.Encode([]rune("12345678901234567890\000"))
        bufSize := uint64(len(buffer))
        fmt.Printf("Result in: %v\n", buffer)

        err := GetRandomSID(buffer, bufSize)
        fmt.Printf("Result in: %v\n", buffer)
        fmt.Println("Err =", err)
        fmt.Println("Called GetRandomSID")
        fmt.Printf("Result out: %v\n", buffer)
    }

func init() {
    fmt.Print("Starting Up\n")
}
```

Example using syscall:

```
    // Package getSID calls SIDgenerator and generates a SID for Retail Pro
    package main

    import (
        "fmt"
        "syscall"
        "unsafe"
    )

    var (
        sidgeneratorDLL, _ = syscall.LoadLibrary("sidgenerator64.dll")
        getRandomSID, _ =  syscall.GetProcAddress(sidgeneratorDLL, "GetRandomSID")
    )

    // GetRandomSID generates random SID, UPC SID or ALU SID
    func GetRandomSID(Buffer *[]byte, BufSize *uint32) (result byte) {
        var nargs uintptr = 2
        fmt.Println(*Buffer)
        ret, _, callErr := syscall.Syscall(uintptr(getRandomSID),  
        nargs,  0,
        uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(Buffer)), 
        uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(BufSize)),
        )

        fmt.Println(*Buffer)

        if callErr != 0 {
            fmt.Println("===== CallErr =====")
            fmt.Println(callErr)
        }
        result = byte(ret)
        return
    }

    func main () {
        defer syscall.FreeLibrary(sidgeneratorDLL)
        buffer := []byte("1234567890123456789012")
        bufSize := uint32(len(buffer))
        fmt.Printf("Result in: %s\n", string(buffer))
        err := GetRandomSID(&buffer, &bufSize)
        fmt.Println("Err =", err)
        fmt.Println("Called GetRandomSID")
        fmt.Printf("Result out: %s\n", string(buffer))
    }

    func init() {
        fmt.Print("Starting Up\n")
    }
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

C# external declarations: --------------------------------

```
[DllImport("SIDGenerator.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)] static extern Boolean GetSIDFromALU(string ALU,  StringBuilder SID,  ref int buflen); 

 [DllImport("SIDGenerator.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]  static extern Boolean GetSIDFromUPC( string UPC,  StringBuilder SID,  ref int buflen); 

 [DllImport("SIDGenerator.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]  static extern Boolean GetRandomSID(StringBuilder SID, ref int buflen);
```

Delphi external declarations: -----------------------------------

```
function GetSIDFromALU( ALU: Pchar;  Buffer: PChar;  var BufSize : integer ): LongBool; stdcall;  external ‘SIDGenerator.dll’; 

function GetSIDFromUPC( UPC: PChar;  Buffer: PChar; var BufSize : integer ): LongBool; stdcall; external ‘SIDGenerator.dll’; 

function GetRandomSID( Buffer: PChar;   var BufSize : integer ): LongBool; stdcall; external ‘SIDGenerator.dll’;
```

In Python I call it with this code and it works beautifully:

```
# Get Retail Pro SID using dll
from ctypes import windll, create_string_buffer, c_int, byref
# os.chdir("c:\\Users\\irving\\Documents\\gitHub\\POImport")
# print(os.getcwd())

# getSID is a Retail Pro dll use to generate SIDs
getSID = windll.SIDGenerator64
randomSID = getSID.GetRandomSID
aluSID = getSID.GetSIDFromALU
upcSID = getSID.GetSIDFromUPC

# Set this by hand now, later set it interactively or by parameter
subsidiary = "1"

def getRandomSID():
    """ Genera un SID aleatorio """
    # Generate a new random SID
    newSID = create_string_buffer(str.encode("12345678901234567890"))
    size = c_int(len(newSID))
    randomSID(newSID, byref(size))
    return newSID.value


def getALUSID(alu):
    """ Genera un SID basado en ALU """
    # Generate a new ALU base SID
    ALU = create_string_buffer(str.encode(alu))
    newSID = create_string_buffer(str.encode("12345678901234567890"))
    size = c_int(len(newSID))
    aluSID(ALU, newSID, byref(size))
    return newSID.value


def getUPCSID(upc):
    """ Genera un SID basado en UPC """
    # Generate a new UPC based SID
    UPC = create_string_buffer(str.encode(upc))
    newSID = create_string_buffer(str.encode("12345678901234567890"))
    size = c_int(len(newSID))
    upcSID(UPC, newSID, byref(size))
    return newSID.value
```

Comment: Please show the Delphi code for the DLL as well, so we can see if 1) the function declaration is even compatible with Go, and 2) that its implementation is accessing Go's data buffer correctly.

Comment: The code is proprietary and I don't have it. I only have the spec that tells me how to use it. I already did the work in Python some time ago. this is what I have:

Comment: C# external declarations: --------------------------------  [DllImport("SIDGenerator.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)] static extern Boolean GetSIDFromALU(string ALU,  StringBuilder SID,  ref int buflen); 
 
 [DllImport("SIDGenerator.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]  static extern Boolean GetSIDFromUPC( string UPC,  StringBuilder SID,  ref int buflen); 
 
 [DllImport("SIDGenerator.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]  static extern Boolean GetRandomSID(StringBuilder SID, ref int buflen);

Comment: As far as I can read, the syscall.Syscall implementation only allows pointers. The function being called expects a buffer which it modifies to return its result. When I try to access that buffer it is either blank if I use syscall, or it panics if I use windows.Call - that is why the fmt.Printf(buffer) is commented. If I uncomment it the program will end in panic.

Comment: I have attached the Python code that uses the dll to get a SID. The main reason I want to move it to go is because a separate executable is easy to deliver without having to install all the Python stack with a whole bunch of packages (Pandas alone is 300 megas).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are passing the pointer to the slice, instead of a pointer to the backing array of the slice.
With your windows.Call code it should be.

```
ret, _, callErr := getRandomSID.Call(uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(&Buffer[0])),
                   uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(&BufSize)))
```

Or your syscall.Syscall version, where its a pointer to the slice.

```
ret, _, callErr := syscall.Syscall(uintptr(getRandomSID),  
        nargs,  0,
        uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(&(*Buffer)[0])), 
        uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(BufSize)),
        )
```

Comment: Thanks! That change did something different. Now I get values back, but they are in a different format (int16). I will see if I can make sense of it. Anyway, it does give an idea of what probably needs to be done.